# How to hide/change asp.net page extension from the viewer?

Tags: asp.net

How to hide/change asp.net page extension from the viewer at the client-side?

I.e. while accessing a page `www.xyz.com/Dir/MyPage.aspx`, the viewer would only see `www.xyz.com/Dir/MyPage.html` or `www.xyz.com/Dir/MyPage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into using URL rewriting. If you are using IIS 7 then you can use [Microsoft URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/expand/URLRewrite). I also use the URL rewrite software [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/). Basically you'll end up creating rewrite rules to append the .aspx extension to the IIS page requests which have no extension. Then all your links created in your code should be created without the .aspx extension.

I realize this response is a bit abbreviated, but I suggest you start learning about URL rewriting.

EDIT: I'm not sure if you'll get this, but I created a screencast and posted it to my blog which covers the basic idea of [how to hide the page extension for ASP.NET](http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/2009/12/07/The-Basics-Of-Hiding-The-Page-Extension-When-Using-ASPNET). I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the routing built into MVC. It's not in any way required to only be used with the MVC Framework, and is quite agnostic.